# Combinar 2 dataset

Tags: powerbi

trato de combinar 2 archivos de datos y no parece que diera resultado.
Quien me puede dar una mano
no publico nada por que son archivos pesados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos que pasos realizas a la hora de combinar?
Con tan solo esa captura me resulta difícil entender que operación intentas realizar y el resultado que obtienes.
Tal vez puedas facilitarnos los dos archivos que intentas combinar con tan solo un top 20, por ejemplo. De ser necesario.

Comment: Aunque no es tan claro los archivos, recuerda que para combinar archivos algo fundamental es que las columnas se llamen igual y tengan el mismo número de columnas. Saludos,